# iOS how to detect cellular data is turned on when wifi is turned on at the same time

Tags: ios

I want to use cellular data to connect the network priority.

So is there a way to detect cellular data's status when wifi is turned on？

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to obtain the cellular data status via [Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony) framework. The class [`CTTelephony​Network​Info`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo) has a property `current​Radio​Access​Technology` that'll tell you which type of cellular network you are registered to at the moment, e.g., `CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE`. You can find all possible values in the [Constants Overview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/core_telephony_constants) of `Core Telephony`.

```
let info = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if info.currentRadioAccessTechnology != nil {
    print("Cellular Data available")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to use iOS 9.0+ `CTCellularData` interface with `cellularDataRestrictionDidUpdateNotifier` block.